# Linking bluetooth library for eclipse cross compile

Tags: c, eclipse, bluetooth

I am trying to cross compile this program onto a beaglebone black
https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html

I know my cross compile set up works as I have followed this video successfully
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJWcRPcqk3g&t=2s

I have installed libbluetooth-dev and the build command

gcc -g -o simplescan simplescan.c -l:libbluetooth.a

works as expected but obviously the binary does not work on the beaglebone.
I can successfully build in Eclipse using the GCC compiler if I use these settings

[image]

When I use the same settings with the cross compiler I get the following error

[image]

I assume due incompatibility with an Arm compiler.
I think I need a way of installing an Arm compatible libbluetooth capability into the arm-linux-gnu-eabi lib files but I am not sure if that is correct or how to do it.
I have tried following this guide solution but it didn't work either
[Linking bluetooth library bluez in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606002/linking-bluetooth-library-bluez-in-eclipse)
and gave this error

[image]

I am using Eclipse Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)

I would be very grateful from any suggestions

Regards
Stephen

Comment: Surely you need a library specifically compiled for your target architecture. You can probably find precompiled one, or compile it yourself from sources. As in https://community.element14.com/challenges-projects/design-challenges/bluetoothunleashed/b/blog/posts/bluetooth-maze-setting-up-bluez-on-the-beaglebone-wireless

Comment: definitely x86 library is not good for ARM target